# NormalizedUserName and NormalizedEmail - ASP.Net Core login

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

When registering a new user (test@here.com), I get the following saved into the [dbo].[AspNetUsers] table:

```
|       Email     |  NormalizedEmail | NormalizedUserName  |     UserName    |
+-----------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|  test@here.com  |  TEST@HERE.COM   |    TEST@HERE.COM    |  test@here.com  |
```

However, I thought that the username was not very user friendly in my layout and wanted to change it to something like:

```
|       Email     |  NormalizedEmail | NormalizedUserName  |     UserName    |
+-----------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|  test@here.com  |  TEST@HERE.COM   |    TEST@HERE.COM    |    John Smith   |
```

On the other hand, I found that by using the ResetPassword in the Account controller or the ChangePassword method in the Manage controller, the NormalizedUserName was overwritten by the UserName to get something like that:

```
|       Email     |  NormalizedEmail | NormalizedUserName  |     UserName    |
+-----------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|  test@here.com  |  TEST@HERE.COM   |      JOHN SMITH     |    John Smith   |
```

Having something like that prevents me to login now as it is using the NormalizedUserName to get identified which is not an email anymore...

**Several questions:**

- Why, when I reset or change my password, my NormalizedUserName gets overwritten?
- Why does it use the NormalizedUserName to get logged? It doesn't make sense to me as we provide an email in the login interface, it should be using the NormalizedEmail instead.

It would be more convenient to make the distinction between user name for display purposes and user email for identification purpose.

Thank you for your help

Sylvain

Comment: Are you using SignInManager and UserManager provided in the AccountController generated by Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, i am using a default ASP.Net Core project with Identity from VS2015 and the Login from AccountController and the ChangePassword from ManageController as provided.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you, like me, changed the scaffolded `RegisterModel` under `Areas.Identity.Pages.Account` to include `UserName`, so that `UserName` is no longer set as `Input.Email`.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.UserName, Email = Input.Email }
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```

Login is handled by Login.cshtml.cs and Login.cshtml, which sends `Input.Email` as the first argument to `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()`. This method actually expects a `UserName`, not an `Email`.

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

I solved this by simply changing the code to look up the correct UserName by Email.

```
string userName = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email).Result.UserName;
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

Comment: I added to Register.cshtml form-group (label and input) for UserName; and to `InputModel` in the Register.cshtml.cs 
But when I break at the line `var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.UserName, Email = Input.Email }` stated above it still shows email as a value. Any help?